# Tensorflow is giving error You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

On line 50 of this gist I am getting the error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,784]
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I am running a basic one layer linear regression soft max neural network but I am running into issues when trying to visualize the cost on tensorboard. Why am I unable to retrieve the summary on line 50?

Line 50:

```
cost, summary = sess.run([cross_entropy, merge], feed_dict={x: batch[0],y_: batch[1]})
```

https://gist.github.com/SamKirkiles/602c7787a9d855b486bbc11232cd7363

Comment: I copied your code (at the github link) into my environment (python 3.x, TF 1.4) and it ran fine. Nor do I see anything obviously wrong at a glance.

Comment: @DavidParks is tensorboard working?

Comment: I didn't fire up tensorboard, but aren't you getting this error when you run the model? Does it matter whether I start tensorboard or not?

Comment: @DavidParks yes when I run the model I can’t get the summary I guess it’s my tensorflow install? Getting many strange error...

Comment: Can you post the errors, and show what you've done **exactly** to generate the errors? I'm not quite following what you're doing.

Comment: @DavidParks Here is the error log on line 50 https://gist.github.com/SamKirkiles/d17a3db437247d7b08869f254b9c938d

Comment: @DavidParks I am using jupyter notebook by the way

Comment: I'm still not seeing an obvious issue. Did you print out `batch[1]` and make sure that you don't have a problem in preprocessing? Perhaps `batch[1] == None`??

Comment: @DavidParks very strange it works when I run outside of jupyter notebook...

Comment: Make sure you don't redefine `y_` in your notebook